# Jersey service not found with recent version

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlets, jersey, http-status-code-404

I wanted to test a simple "Hello World" jersey service using Maven and Tomcat (7.0) in Eclipse. Maven downloaded the most recent version 1.17, but everytime I try to access the page I retreive a 404. However after changing back to version 1.9 it works as expected. Did anything change between those version or am I missing something?

What I do is calling `localhost:8080/rngservice/rest/hello` which gives a 404 error when I'm using jersey versions beyond 9. Using version 9 however works as intended and returns  the HTML page.

Any suggestions?

My code:

```
package service.test;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/hello")
public class RNGResource {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String getItHTML() {
    return "<htm> <title> " + "Got it!" + "</title> </html>";
  }
}
```

I don't use a web.xml but a `PackagesResourceConfig` for the servlet configuration

```
package service.test;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/rest/*")
public class RNGServiceApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {

  public RNGServiceApplication() {
   super("service.test");
  }
}
```

The Maven .pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>service</groupId>
  <artifactId>rngservice</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>rngservice</name>

  <build>
  <!-- ... -->
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404, it would seem that the service was not able to start correctly.  Are you sure there are no errors during Tomcat/application startup?

Comment: There are no errors for both versions, the logs produce the same. However using the 1.9 version of jersey there's also this log information; `com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer addServletWithApplication
INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named service.test.random.RNGServiceApplication, at the servlet mapping, /rest/*, with the Application class of the same name` This Isn't produced using the 1.17 version which might explain the 404 error. But the question remains why does this happen?

Comment: I don't know how to promote this to attract more attention.. but i'm having the same issue still, with Jersey 1.18, with Maven 3, Tomcat 7 in Eclipse 4.3. I guess this is due to how maven processes the jersey library. If I created a "dynamic web project" and put in the jersey facet manually, Tomcat finds the REST resource happily. When I convert the exactly same project to a Maven project and let it handle the dependencies, the very same Tomcat throws 404 errors ever after..

Comment: With some more experiments, I found that taking the Jersey library resolution away from Maven (i.e. manually adding it to Eclipse) makes Tomcat happy.

Comment: Sorry for an incremental update -- I just found Maven works with Jersey 2.5.1 for Tomcat 7, with dep configured as instructed in [this article](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html)